# Highchart Generate SVG off-screen with Java

Tags: java, svg, highcharts, batik

I am wondering if there is a Java API for HighChart (Not the exporting API) which can generate the svg based on the supplied parameters which can then be later converted to png using Batik **without going anywhere near HTTP requests**.

At the moment the only way I can think of is to POST to a dummy page with the Chart points then export to SVG and submit to the Export-service with Javascript which converts it into PNG with Batik which in turn returns it as an image stream.

However all I would need is to get the image stream in the JVM supplied by parameters from the DB. The above way needs 2 request-response pairs and apart from that it is not the cleanest solution, I think it generates overhead as this operation would be quite frequent on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your own server or use solution described here: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use API to generate highcharts. Download and try the following project provided by One2team

https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export